# React Js Get Data with Fetch limit return

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I am new to React and was following a tutorial this React tutorial to get data with fetch. Why when I append it with a limit in the query it still returns 10 results?

````
    import React from 'react'

export default function UsersData() {
    return (
        <div>
            
        </div>
    )
}
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export default function UsersData() {
  const [Users, fetchUsers] = useState([])

  const getData = () => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_limit=8')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
        fetchUsers(res)
      })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getData()
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <h2>React Fetch API Example</h2>
      <ul>
        {Users.map((item, i) => {
          return <li key={i}>{item.name}</li>
        })}
      </ul>
    </>
  )
}```
````

Comment: First of all, what I recommend you is that, just start with lower letter for the state variable in order to prevent mixing the components and variables. So you can have it like this,

   ` const [users, setUsers] = useState([]) `

And when I try it returns 8 users for me, can you show what you have in console.log ?

Answer (score 1):

```
    var params = {
       method: 'GET',
       headers: {
          "cache-control": 'no-cache',
          pragma: 'no-cache',
         }
       };


fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_limit=8", params)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
      console.log(res)
  })
```

can you try like this ?

Comment: Its working now. I had written the app.js file incorrectly and was using posts instead of users. Thanks for your help.